# File import and save with local macro like Stata in R

Tags: r

all

I am a beginner in R, but I usually use Stata.
I want to import excel files in R and rename some columns of each 4 files, respectively. And I also want to save it to another file using just one for loop.

```
s <- "./20211210094220.xlsx"
b <- "./20211210094740.xlsx"
c <- "./20211210095253.xlsx"
g <- "./20211210095616.xlsx"

for (hos in c(s,b,c,g)) {
  drug <- read_excel(hos)
  drug <- rename(drug, "x" = "y")
  drug <- rename(drug, "a" = "b")
  all_of(hos)2 <- drug
}
```

The target files are s, b, c, and g, and the saving file names I want are s2, b2, c2, g2.

I referred to this site, [R for Stata user](https://www.matthieugomez.com/statar/macros.html), and I also know how to execute those code using local macro in Stata. But It did not run.

Please tell me how to run that code in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. read in all `xlsx` files in your root directory (or modify if other)
2. same them all in a list `df.list`
3. rename with assigning `names`

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)

names(df.list) <- c("s2", "b2", "c2", "g2")
```

Comment: The names aren't supposed to be the **file** names? Not the env. names. You could use `purrr::walk`  with write_csv.